# Files automatic remove from project folder using Visual Studio 2015 Cordova

Tags: visual-studio, cordova, visual-studio-2015

When I saved File but automatic remove from project folder using Visual studio 2015 Cordova

We update every tools but nothing working.

Please solve my issue.

Thanks

Comment: Could you be a bit more specific? What do you mean by 'save'? Does it remove the file you save? Or changes are reverted when you save? 
Cordova build works?

Comment: yes when we edit anything in file.. then save it.... then remove from project folder www. Please give me solutions. Thanks for reply

Comment: What project template are you using? Empty app (Apache Cordova) for Typescript? Also make sure not to work in the platform www folders. They will be overriden, once you build your app, see the [docs here](https://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/latest/reference/cordova-cli/#www)

Comment: i m using visual studio 2015 cordova.. just explain to you.. when we edit any file in visual studio 2015 cordova then it remove from the project tree. i do not know why happening last few weeks.